# How to replace array items by splitting multiple array values by comma

Tags: php, arrays

Given is an array of arrays:

```
$items = array(
  array(
    'id' => '1',
    'property_a' => 'a,b,c',
    'property_b' => '1,2,3'
    'property_c' => 'x,y'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '2',
    'property_a' => 'b,c,d',
    'property_b' => '3,4,5',
    'property_c' => 'x,y'
  )  
);
```

and each item in this array should be split by some but not all values that are seperated by comma:

```
$splitItemsBy = array('property_a', 'property_b');
```

The result should be an array of items with **unique** combinations of the defined $splitItemsBy key values.

**Desired result:**

```
[
  ['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'a', 'property_b' => '1', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'b', 'property_b' => '1', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'c', 'property_b' => '1', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'a', 'property_b' => '2', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'a', 'property_b' => '3', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'b', 'property_b' => '2', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'b', 'property_b' => '3', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'c', 'property_b' => '2', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'c', 'property_b' => '3', 'property_c' => 'x,y']

  ['id' => '2', 'property_a' => 'b', 'property_b' => '3', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '2', 'property_a' => 'c', 'property_b' => '3', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '2', 'property_a' => 'd', 'property_b' => '3', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '2', 'property_a' => 'b', 'property_b' => '4', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '2', 'property_a' => 'b', 'property_b' => '5', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '2', 'property_a' => 'c', 'property_b' => '4', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '2', 'property_a' => 'c', 'property_b' => '5', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '2', 'property_a' => 'd', 'property_b' => '4', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
  ['id' => '2', 'property_a' => 'd', 'property_b' => '5', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
]
```

Is there an performant and elegant way to do this in PHP?

Thank you in advance for all submissions. Bonus Points for solving that in SQL. Go!

## Edit: The way I solved it

To show that you don't actually do my work, here's my approach (which kind of feels too complicated).

[...]

Comment: This sounds like you just want people to write your code for you, without actually having tried yourself.

Comment: Edited the question and included my way to solve it to proof that you don't have to do my work. Hope answers are not going to be biased from that.

Comment: Show how the db tables are laid out if you want an SQL query. Oh, and what db you're using.

Comment: Don't have that in a DB right now and it would heavily depend on the SQL dialect. I'd say the table is all string columns but the id is int unsigned. SQLite3 would be nice but to get an idea how to approach this, any SQL dialect would be fine.

Comment: Oh and it's not that I would like to have it in SQL but if there's an easier solution to do this kind of task in SQL it would be nice. Therefore if it requires SQL features not available in "whatever-database-product" and I have to use another just to solve this problem, that is ok, hints are very welcome.

Comment: The problem is that if you don't know how many sets you're gonna have (as seen below) query is gonna get very ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PostgreSQL

```
SELECT id, 
  unnest(property_a) as property_a,
  property_b,
  property_c
FROM (
SELECT id, 
  property_a,
  unnest(property_b) as property_b,
  property_c
FROM
  sets) AS q;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/30ac1/5)

Or more traditionaly with data in properties in diffrent tables (property_c could be stored in one row as a string but that's not really the point)

```
SELECT a.id, 
  a.property_a,
  b.property_b,
  array_agg(c.property_c) as property_c
FROM  a 
  JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
  JOIN c ON b.id=c.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.property_a,b.property_b;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9462a/3)

Answer (score 1):

If you reorder your desired result for `id = 1`, it becomes a lot clearer how the groupings work:

```
['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'a', 'property_b' => '1', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'b', 'property_b' => '1', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'c', 'property_b' => '1', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'a', 'property_b' => '2', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'b', 'property_b' => '2', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'c', 'property_b' => '2', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'a', 'property_b' => '3', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'b', 'property_b' => '3', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
['id' => '1', 'property_a' => 'c', 'property_b' => '3', 'property_c' => 'x,y']
```

Using a simplified version of the original array, I can get the above with :

```
$set1 = 'a,b,c';
$set2 = '1,2,3';

$array1 = explode(",",$set1);
$array2 = explode(",",$set2);

foreach($array1 as $set1_member) {
    foreach($array2 as $set2_member) {
        $collection[] = array($set1_member, $set2_member);
    }
}
```

Which, when I echo out the array with `json_encode`, returns:

```
[
["a","1"],
["a","2"],
["a","3"],
["b","1"],
["b","2"],
["b","3"],
["c","1"],
["c","2"],
["c","3"]
]
```

Comment: Right, but that is very limited to just two sets. What if $splitItemsBy = array('property_a', 'property_b'); contains more properties to split? Or rather an unknown amount of properties.

Comment: The number of properties in each set is not the same as the number of sets you are "combining" (for lack of a better term). The code above should handle two sets with any number of properties in either.

Comment: it doesn't cover if there's $set3 or an unknown amount of $setX which in the original quesion is 'property_a', 'property_b' and so on.

Comment: The code can be tweaked to use foreach recursively for each set. Will need to think on best approach